# Typescript: how to extend interfaces for nested field and assign value to object?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following interfaces :

```
interface MyType1 {
  field1: string;
    options: {
        basicOption1: string;
        basicOption2: string; 
    };
}

interface MoreOptions {
    moreOptions1: string;
    moreOptions2: string;
}
```

I extend the field options of interface MyType1 :

```
interface MyType2 extends MyType1{
    options: {
        basicOption1: string; // How to remove it, yet declared in MyType1
        basicOption2: string; // How to remove it, yet declared in MyType1
        moreOptions1: string;
        moreOptions2: string; 
    };
}
```

If I omit lines : `basicOptions1:string;`and `basicOptions2:string;`, compiler complains. So, I add them. But, is it possible to remove them and only keep lines : `moreOptions1:string;` and `moreOptions2:string;` for the additional options.

Following, how could I assign an object of type `Mytype2` from two objects of type `MyType1` and `MoreOptions` ?

For example (Rq : I test other things but also unsuccessful) :

```
let myobj1: MyType1 = { field1:"field1", options:{ basicOption1:"basicOption1", basicOption2:"basicOption2" } };
let moreOptions: MoreOptions = { moreOptions1: "moreOptions1", moreOptions2: "moreOptions2" }

let myobj2: MyType2 = { ...myobj1, options: {...moreOptions} };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can intersect the desired types for `options` property:

```
interface MyType2 extends MyType1 {
    options: MyType1["options"] & MoreOptions
}
```

Concerning `MyType2 extends MyType1` and the error:

Existing properties in `MyType1` like `options` have to be identical in `MyType2`, they do not get overwritten or merged in somehow. Other properties like `field1` are automatically carried over.

---

> Following, how could I assign an object of type Mytype2 from two objects of type MyType1 and MoreOptions ?

You can use object spread, which will merge all objects and in case of equally named properties choose the right-most one ([Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=35&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOECMyA3gLABQyyMwEANgCb4BcyAzmFKAOYDc5lAexxhgAkKxakKlGZQBGcVsAQB5YaJDM2Hbn2mz5i5WpFiATC3acQvZP2QBfPQ-LlQkWIhSoBUCCY1WYntKAFtff3UxVi0rXRDkcL8A6Itta15yFzI3cGh4JDQsXAgzZAgAD0gQeiCMbDxCKVkhU3EWepL8AG0AIlbA3oBdZAAyNAiU8SzXMnoIBFo4P2QEaLBkMC1Oxr15xeWUNfENpMiwDsmo8T1j9k20ndLkAF5iADpPrYAaZAHoySfd5bd7-cS-IFnEwOBxAA)):

```
declare const t1: MyType1;
declare const moreOpt: MoreOptions;
const t2: MyType2 = {...t1, options: {...t1.options, ...moreOpt}};
```

Comment: Concerning the second question, is there a mean to add moreOptions to myobj2 ? When I read your answer, it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you give me a simple idea !!!  It works. `let myobj2: MyType2 = { ...myobj1, options: {...myobj1.options, ...moreOptions} };` Could you complete your answer an after I will accept it.